# How to make pycharm resolve reference compiled module in the current project folder

Tags: python, pycharm, compiled

Here is a sample project:

[image]

speedup.pyd is a compiled module with one function `fast_add()`.

But pycharm can't resolve references in this compiled module.

I tried make source root, and then add source roots to PYTHONPATH.

also tried add the source folder to Interpreter Paths.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this option is "hiding" and not easy to find...

Go to PyCharm "Preferences" screen (from the Menu: PyCharm -> Preferences). Then go to: Project -> Project Interpreter, click on the setup "wheel" and choose "More"

[image]

Click on the marked icon in the screenshot below (if you'll hover the cursor it'll say: "Show paths for the selected interpreter"):

[image]

Then click on the "plus" icon and add the path to your module:

[image]

And you should be good to go :)